# responsive header logo with text

Tags: html, css, responsive

I would like for my header to change when viewed on mobile. On the big screen is shows the logo with the text beside it. On mobile I would like for the text to go below the logo and maybe even just 1 line with a bullet between. Right now when I view on mobile, the logo and text resize, but the text gets too big and falls off the screen.

Here is a link to the site:
jeepscycleclub.x10host.com

Here is my css for the #pageheader:

```
#pageheader {
    -moz-align-items: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: flex;
    -moz-justify-content: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #2f2f37;
    max-height: 15vh;
}

    #pageheader img {
        max-height:15vmax;
    }
```

and my html:

```
<div id="pageheader">
<img src="images/pageheader.gif">
    <header>
    <h2 style="font-size: 3vh;">Club Info: 316-755-0909</h2>
    <h2 style="font-size: 3vh;">FM 100.9 for Race PA System</h2>
    </header>
</div>
```

This is just my test site so I can get everything done before going live with it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Look into media queries to apply different css for different resolutions

Comment: I've looked in that I just don't know how to change my html based on the size. I'm pretty new to css so I'm still learning how it all works.

Comment: you dont have to change your markup. instead of using inline markup styling, use your stylesheet. Google css media queries, and you'll probably find some good examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `flex-wrap: wrap;` for this. And you have to change the width/max-width, otherwise there won't be space for the text when it goes under the logo.

```css
#pageheader {
    -moz-align-items: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: flex;
    -moz-justify-content: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #2f2f37;

    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

    #pageheader img {
        max-height:15vmax;
    }
```

```html
<div id="pageheader">
<img src="http://placehold.it/150x80/a0f">
    <header>
    <h2 style="font-size: 3vh;">Club Info: 316-755-0909</h2>
    <h2 style="font-size: 3vh;">FM 100.9 for Race PA System</h2>
    </header>
</div>
```

Comment: That worked! Thank You! Now one more thing, is there a way of instead of having 2 lines, it would switch the text to one line with a bullet between them?

for example on the small screen show this:
Logo
Club Info: 316-755-0909 • FM 100.9 for Race PA System

for the big screen show the regular with the logo to the left and the text to the right.

Comment: well, you can try to also gibe the `header` element `display: flex` and `flex-wrap: wrap`. Then it depends on the width of this element if it's broken into two lines or displayed in one line.